# Spinners values are not setting correctly

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, hashmap, android-spinner

I am fetching data from online XML web URL and getting data in successufully. I am using **hashmap key and value** from it...and the key and values I am getting is like this below in my LOGCAT-

```
{
Jackfruit=[Cabbage, Kesar, Amond], 
Date=[van, hall, Brinjal], 
Amond=[hall, van, Brinjal]
}
```

**1.** When i first launch the android app the spinner and spinner2 gets populated in spinner all data are populated correctly but in spinner2 all the keys value are showing ...but it should show only the values of key displaying in spinner1

**2.** List item in both the spinners are showing correctly when I change the spinner1 key value then all the drop downs are showing with the correct values.

**3.** When I click on spinner2 value then it acts as key and starts showing is value in spinner instead it should place that value which I clicks.

**I sketched it in notepad have a look to the problem**

```
{
Jackfruit=[Cabbage, Kesar, Amond], 
Date=[van, hall, Brinjal], 
Amond=[hall, van, Brinjal]
}
```

[image: Problem sketch]

And my code is below 
**MainActivity.java**

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi") 
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, OnClickListener { 

    ArrayList<String> title; 
    ArrayList<String> title2; 
    Button button; 
    Spinner spinner; 
    Spinner spinner2; 
    private EditText FromFruitsDateEtxt; 
    //private EditText toDateEtxt; 

    private DatePickerDialog FromFruitsDatePickerDialog; 
    //private DatePickerDialog toDatePickerDialog; 

    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter; 

    ArrayAdapter<String> FromFruits_adapter; 
    ArrayAdapter<String> FromFruits_adapter2; 
    Map<String, List<String>> values = new HashMap<String, List<String>>(); 
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) 
    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

        title = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        title2 = new ArrayList<String>(); 

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); 
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1); 
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this); 

        spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2); 
        spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this); 
        dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US); 
        findViewsById(); 

        setDateTimeField(); 
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) { 
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build(); 
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
        } 

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) { 
                parse(); 

                FromFruits_adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, title); 
                FromFruits_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); 

                FromFruits_adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, title2); 
                FromFruits_adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); 

                spinner.setAdapter(FromFruits_adapter); 
                FromFruits_adapter2.clear(); 
                FromFruits_adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
                spinner2.setAdapter(FromFruits_adapter2); 
            } 

            private Object FromFruits_adapter(int i) { 
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                return null; 
            } 
        });  
    } 

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) { 
        String lang_Name = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(); 
        List<String> lang_Key = values.get(lang_Name); 
        FromFruits_adapter2.clear(); 
        for(String s : lang_Key){ 
            FromFruits_adapter2.insert(s, FromFruits_adapter2.getCount()); 
        } 
        FromFruits_adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), ""+lang_Key, 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    } 

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) { 
    } 

    protected void parse() { 
        try { 
            URL url = new URL("web url www.xyz.xml"); 
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); 
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder(); 
            Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream())); 
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize(); 

            NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Fruits"); 
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) { 
                Element el = (Element) nodeList.item(i); 
                // get the a:W value 
                String awValue = el.getElementsByTagName("FromFruits").item(0).getTextContent(); 
                // add the above value in our map as key if it isn't present in the map, this key will 
                // have a list associated with it in which ALL the values for a:R will be stored, if 
                // the awValue key is present then you just add the new a:R value to its list 
                if (!values.containsKey(awValue)) { 
                    values.put(awValue, new ArrayList<String>()); 
                }
                // also add the value pointed by a:R to the list associated with a:W 
                String arValue = el.getElementsByTagName("ToFruits").item(0).getTextContent(); 
               values.get(awValue).add(arValue); 

                // Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value: " + arValue); 
            } 
            Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value: " + values); 
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) { 
                Node node = nodeList.item(i); 

                Element fstElmnt = (Element) node; 
                NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("FromFruits"); 
                Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0); 
                nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes(); 

                NodeList websiteList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("ToFruits"); 
                Element websiteElement = (Element) websiteList.item(0); 
                websiteList = websiteElement.getChildNodes(); 

                title.add(((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue()); 
            } 
            NodeList nodeList2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("Fruits"); 
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList2.getLength(); i++) { 
                Node node = nodeList2.item(i); 

                Element fstElmnt = (Element) node; 
                NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("ToFruits"); 
                Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0); 
                nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes(); 
                title2.add(((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue()); 
            } 
            Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>(title); 
            title = new ArrayList<String>(set); 
            // Collection<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>(months); 
            Set<String> set2 = new LinkedHashSet<String>(title2); 
            title2 = new ArrayList<String>(set2); 
            System.out.println("list are"); 
            System.out.println(set); 
            System.out.println("list 2 are"); 
            System.out.println(set2); 
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e); 
        } 
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onClick(View view) { 
        if(view == FromFruitsDateEtxt) { 
            FromFruitsDatePickerDialog.show(); 
        } else { 
            Log.d("errorrrr", "soryy"); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

**The problem in the  sketch can be seen**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by myself and one of my friend Ricardo Barroca from stackoverflow
see to my commented out the statements

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
//spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

This solved my spinner2 problem of click which was fetching the values instead of making itself to set to spinner.

And from below code it cleared the pre populated values to spinner1 and spinner2

```
from_adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, title);
from_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            title2.clear();
            from_adapter2=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, title2);
            from_adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(from_adapter);
    //from_adapter2.clear();
    //from_adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
    spinner2.setAdapter(from_adapter2);
```